# NHibernate mapping class properties to Rows not Columns

Tags: c#, nhibernate, properties, nhibernate-mapping

Is it possible to map a class with each property stored as a row in the table, not a column. The scenario is where we persist global options to the database. We store the options in an 'Options' class that has a property per option, i.e. "Expand Menu", "Save on Exit" etc.

Rather than store each option in its own table column, we would simply like to have a table with each of the class properties stored as a new row, identified by a Enum.

Is this possible?

(C# Winforms)

Answer (score 1):

Using NHibernate's `EntityMode.Map` might help solve this problem.  It does mean that you might have to put your global options in a `Dictionary` collection, but you can always implement an Option class that abstracts the underlying `Dictionary`.

NHibernate provides the ability to map a Dictionary dynamically to a table.  See NHibernate's reference on [Dynamic Models](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels)

Comment: Wow, hadn't heard of anything like this before! Sounds really useful!